# Application Insight Analytics SDK

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Is there an SDK exists which can be used to run analytic queries against [application insight](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-analytics/) . I would like to run analytics queries from C# code  and trigger mails in an unusual events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it is in preview as far as I know. See https://dev.applicationinsights.io/.